# Why am i getting a 0 result in this program when i enter 3?

Tags: c

If i enter a value lets say "3" i get a result of 0. Please explain why and if there is a way please show me. Should I use float?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getResult (int nVal)
int c , f;
int nExp;
double dSum;
f = 1;
dSum = 0;

nExp = nVal;
for (c = 1; c <= nVal; c++)
{
    f = f * c;
    dSum += f / nExp;
    nExp = nExp * nVal;
}

return  dSum;
int main ()
{

int nVal, nCompute;
double dSum;
printf("Enter Number to be Computed");
scanf("%d",&nVal);

nCompute = getResult (nVal);

printf("%d", nCompute);

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: without using math.h ^^^

Comment: Use float not int.

Comment: use `double`, not `float`

Comment: I've rolled back your edit because it completely changed the nature of the question after you already had an answer. If you have a different question, please create a new post.

Answer (score 2):

`f` and `nExp` are `int`s, so you're dividing them using [integer division](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_(mathematics)#Of_integers), keeping only the "whole" part of the result, to the left of the decimal point, which is zero. Instead, you define one or both of them as `double`s, so you'd be performing floating-point division.

Comment: i changed them to double but im still getting a result of 0

Comment: change every `int` to `float` including the ones in `main()` function and the argument of `getResult()` function.

Comment: And don't forget to change `printf`'s format specifier accordingly.

Comment: ooohh alright i solved the question thanks